# Overriding styles without able to use !important or same property name

Tags: html, css

I have two different css-files (master.css, custom.css).
On master.css there are defined some styles ( eg. #largediv {*width*: 100px;} )

Can i override property *width* on custom.css without using !important or using same property name (width)?

I am using Joomla and master.css is core file and therefore it cannot be edited.

Comment: It depends which file has been loaded first.

Comment: Yes, if you select it with a parent element it will override.  Such as #wrapper #largediv { code here };

Answer (score 3):

You could use a CSS rule with a higher specificity. For example, `body #largediv {}` in custom.css would override any mentions of `#largediv` in the master.css.

Specificity is one of the least understood principles of CSS. More information is available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thanks, but as i said i cannot use width property because it will break layout.

Comment: @RogerWayne So when you say `Can i override property width on custom.css...`, what are you trying to override the width with? You can use `width: auto` if you don't want a specific width (ie you want to effectively remove the `width` style)

Answer (score 1):

Depends how the css files are loaded in a case where master is loaded then custom, the rendered css will reflect the latest value. Example:

```css
#largediv{width: 50px; border:1pt solid red;}/*master.css*/
#largediv{width: 100px; border:1pt solid blue;}/*custom.css*/
```

```html
<div id="largediv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i said i cannot use width property because it will break layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the the specific element. So the custom.css has a more precisely path to the element. Something like this:

HMTL

```
<div id="largediv" class="inCustomCss"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.inCustomCSS {
     your css style.
    }
```

Comment: This would not work, as an ID has a higher specificity than a class in CSS

Answer (score -1):

if you write `#largediv {width: 567px;}` in your custom.css and the custom.css is loaded after the master.css (what I assume), then you will overwrite the property.